# Getting “x-amzn-Remapped-WWW-Authenticate instead of WWW-Authenticate and jetty client not able to recognise

Tags: amazon-web-services, jetty

AWS API gateway remaps WWW-Authenticate header as x-amazn-remapped-WWW-Authenticate. Our customers use java jetty client and jetty client is failing since jetty client is looking for WWW-Authenticate header

1. How to send WWW-Authenticate from AWS API gateway
2. Any fix on the Jetty client?

I tried to use gateway response on 
1. AWS API gateway response - to handle 400 
2. Integration Response  - to handle 400 requests and then set the WWW-authenticate header 
    
    `#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
    $input.json("$")
    #if($inputRoot.toString().contains("error"))
    #set($context.responseOverride.status = 400)
    #set($context.responseOverride.header.WWW-Authenticate = 'value')`

Comment: This statement would be true in any HTTP Client, and isn't unique to the Jetty HTTP Client.

Answer (score 6):

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html) documents this behavior.

This behavior cannot be overwritten. If it could, how would you tell the difference between your server sending a `401 Unauthorized` and a `WWW-Authenticate` header (indicating that you passed through API Gateway fine and you must authenticate with the server), or API Gateway sending a `401 Unauthorized` and a `WWW-Authenticate` header (indicating that your request never reached the server and that you must authenticate with API Gateway)?

Comment: Yes, I understand the behavior! But the customers who are consuming the API's are having issues. The Oracle Jetty client by default looks for WWW-Authenticate response header with 401 status code when the oAuth token is expired. Sending x-amazon-remapped-WWW-Authenticate is making the API not cosumable.

Comment: The behavior Amazon is doing is correct, you have a traditional HTTP intermediary (the gateway) and a HTTP endpoint (the server) both in this picture, if the intermediary needs auth, then it would be incorrect to return the `WWW-Authenticate` header from the endpoint.  It would be wrong for the HTTP User-Agent (client) to respond with the auth for the endpoint if the intermediary is the one asking.  What if the endpoint and intermediary had different credentials?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, when setting up proxies like nginx, we usually have a control of what we do with the headers. And if we want it to be just a dumb proxy, it should be able to pass the response headers unchanged. And if we don't set up Authorizers on AWS side, then the Gateway won't respond with 401 - so we know for a fact that it has to be our app.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev the minute you setup authentication on a nginx proxy it can no longer be "just a dumb proxy".

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, people don't usually set up authentication at the level of the reverse proxy. And while API Gateway has a notion of Authorizers, they're optional - you can work without them. If we use Proxy Integration with no Authorizers, then it's just a dumb proxy. And in this scenario it doesn't make sense to rename any of the headers.

Comment: The renaming is being done by AWS, because it has an authn/authz requirement.  Reverse proxies with authn/authz are growing in popularity, even within tightly controlled internal environments (typically done to enforce periodic upgrades of behaviors, they change the authn/authz occasionally, and those that didn't get the memo are no longer allowed to use the proxy until they upgrade their code).

Comment: It looks like the way clients are _supposed_ to tell the difference of Proxy (APIG) auth vs resource auth is by watching for a `407` response and a `Proxy-Authenticate` header. Excerpt in my answer below.

Comment: So why is Lambda remapping the header when I am NOT using API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

The limitation mentioned in Joey's answer indeed can't be overridden, however you *can* return `WWW-Authentication` without it being overridden, if you set up a [lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) that handles the authentication in front of your endpoint.

After setting up the custom lambda authorizer for the API endpoint, configure an 'Unauthorized' gateway response having the header `WWW-Authenticate: 'Basic'`, which will be in the response returned, if the lambda authorizer denies access.

Answer (score 0):

As called out by @JoakimErdfelt, API Gateway appears to be doing the correct thing here. I wanted to know why, so I did some digging and found [this Proxy authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#proxy_authentication) description from Mozilla:

> **Proxy authentication**
>
> The same challenge and response mechanism can be used for proxy authentication. As both resource authentication and proxy authentication can coexist, a different set of headers and status codes is needed. In the case of proxies, the challenging status code is `407` (Proxy Authentication Required), the `Proxy-Authenticate` response header contains at least one challenge applicable to the proxy, and the `Proxy-Authorization` request header is used for providing the credentials to the proxy server.