# How does one handle x-amzn-remapped-authorization when consuming APIs on frontend?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

While using Laravel Vapor, I encountered my first taste of server-less, in form of a caveat. The `authorization` header which the API serves to allow the frontend to authenticated is being remapped as `x-amzn-remapped-authorization`.

This poses a challenge as to at what part of the application should I cleanse this as a lot of the frontend and the underlying authentication packages use the `authorization` header instead of `x-amzn-remapped-authorization`. Maybe an axios interceptor can help me cleanse this?

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    config.headers.authorization = localStorage.getItem("token");
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

[Getting “x-amzn-Remapped-WWW-Authenticate instead of WWW-Authenticate and jetty client not able to recognise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037317/getting-x-amzn-remapped-www-authenticate-instead-of-www-authenticate-and-jetty#comment102525229_58042589) claims that this behaviour is correct, since with API Gateway you hve three parties involved:

- (A) Consumer
- (B) API Gateway
- (C) Provider

I understand the argumentation in the following way: Since it could be necessary that (B) requires authorization itself, it needs to claim the authorization header and therefore needs to remap. In this scenario "authorization" is used for successful authorization with (B) and x-amzn-remapped-authorization is used for successful authorization with the backend (C).

Comment: I just edited my frontend to capture the new header.

Comment: I gave up and did the same. Thanks.